# Why am I not able to revoke GraphAPI Permissions in Graph Explorer Sandbox?

Tags: azure, permissions, entra-id, graph

When I go to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer and log in with my Azure account, I cannot revoke access to mail.send:

[image]

And am presented with this message:

**"You require Directory.Read.All and DelegatedPermissionGrant.ReadWrite.All to be able to revoke consent to permissions"**

[image]

**So I granted access here:**

[image]

**And Here:**

[image]

However it appears that Admin Consent is required and I am not sure how to approve.

Thanks in advance.